# Trying to set up SSH keys, but instructions aren't clear

Tags: remote-access, ssh-keys

Every SSH tutorial or explanation I find seems to forget right in the middle that there are two computers or servers involved.

I am trying to create a website hosted on a remote server. I generated keys so I can access the website. Now I need to access the website from my computer.

So I have these keys and can't figure out what to do with them to make them work. Every tutorial or explanation says I need to generate keys for my computer system and keep them in a file that doesn't exist. That not only doesn't make any sense, but doesn't seem to have anything to do with accessing the remote server from my computer with the keys to the website that have already been generated for that purpose. Obviously some piece of information is getting lost. Can somebody please explain what I am supposed to do?

It seems like it should be simple, but WHERE do I put WHICH key, and how do I initiate the connection?
I've been using terminal in Linux for years. You would think I would know this in my sleep, but I don't.

Answer (score 1):

You always generate a *pair* of keys: A *private* key, which you should keep secret, and a *public* key, which other people are allowed to see.

So for keys that allow you to remotely access a website, these keys identify *you* (they prove your identity). Which means the private key should stay on *your* computer, while the public key should be on the *remote* computer.

So, concretely, you'll generate an `id_rsa` (private) and an `id_rsa.pub` (public). key. Just keep both in the `.ssh` directory in your home directory on your computer (normally, you'd create them after cd-ing into that directory). The `id_rsa` key will be automatically used by `ssh` as your identity, while the `id_rsa.pub` key will be ignored, but you'll know where it is if you need it.

On the remote side, in the `.ssh` directory of the account you want to log into, there's an `authorized_keys` file, which contains a list of public keys, one per line. This file is read by `sshd` to find out who is allowed to connect to this account.

Either edit that file and add the contents of your local `id_rsa.pub` in a new line, or, if the file wasn't there, or should only contain one key, just copy your local `id_rsa.pub` to `authorized_keys`.

That's it. Of course you can use scripts that automate this process, but this is what it boils down to.

Comment: Yes, I did that with a gui on the website configuration page. I got the public and private keys. I just don't know how to use them since all the instructions I've found are talking about accessing my own computer from keys generated on my owm computer,  which isn't what I'm trying to do.

Comment: The answer explains how to access some other computer with a pair of keys, no matter how you generated that keys: Assuming RSA keys, you put the private key into `id_rsa` on your computer, and the public key into the `authorized_keys` file on the other computer. You didn't mention any website in the question, and I wouldn't recommend using a random website to generate your keys (because whoever owns the website will know your private key). If this website is supplied by whoever owns the remote computer, it may automatically put the public key into `authorized_hosts`.

Comment: Anyhow, if the question depends on that website, please add details to the question.

Comment: I feel so silly. I had it right the first time I tried it. Then I second-guessed myself and the way I had understood the man pages when it didn't work. I had forgotten my website was still on shared hosting. I needed to move to a dedicated server and it works just fine from either direction.

Answer (score 0):

By default your ssh keys is saved on folder `/home/[youruser]/.ssh/`. To use ssh connection you can use ways:

`ssh [username]@[server] -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa -p [port-number-of-ssh]`

example of usage:
`ssh dies@dies.com -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa -p 22`

or you can ignore key and type password of connection using parameter to ignore key verification, see example:

`ssh dies@dies.com -o PubkeyAuthentication=no -p 22`

good lucky to you!

Comment: Thanks. Home/user/.ssh was a big part of what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Assumption, same user login name on both serverA and serverB.  You want to log into serverB from serverA.

On serverA, if you have not already done so, generate the ssh key pair:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -N ''
```

On serverA, run the following command so set up permissions so that when ssh-ing from serverA to serverB you are not prompted for a password:

```
ssh-copy-id serverB
```

You will be prompted for a password.

If the ssh-copy-id command was successful, validate you can ssh from serverA to serverB without being prompted for a password.

```
ssh serverB
```

If you get into serverB, you are done.

Hope this helps

Comment: The keys were generated in the website admin panel by graphical interface. Then it said to save the private key on my computer. Everywhere I've looked for further info says to generate the keys on my computer, but I couldn't figure out how the web server would recognize them. Maybe this has been so confusing to me because I have limited graphical access to a hosted website (I'm not the server admin). I would only have full admin access to the database I installed for the website on that server.

Comment: I just wanted to clarify that this simplifies the scenario I keep seeing on the internet and is much easier than the way the webhost expects it to be done since I have a handy terminal and know where my files are, but until I have ssh access to the remote server I don't have full control on that side. Very helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately permission is denied.